# How do I save the text that the user enters into a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am basically making a simple notes application. In my`ViewController` I have a `UITextView`. I want the text that the user types in the `UITextView` to be saved so that the next time the user opens the app it is still there. How would I go about doing that? I want it to save onto the device so they can type and save a large amount of text.

Comment: How are you saving your note? Are you using Core Data?

Comment: I can't save anything yet, forgive me for not knowing much about this, I'm still learning how to code... I thing I an using Core Data @AdrianB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save it easily using **NSUserDefaults** too.

Add this line of code in your button save event or can add it in your UITextViewDelegate method **textViewDidEndEditing**: But don't forget to assign delegate of textview using

```
textView.delegate = self;
```

Now to store use following code:

```
NSString *valueToSave = textView.text;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"preferenceName"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

And to retrieve it back later, use this in your viewDidLoad: or viewWillAppear:

```
NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
stringForKey:@"preferenceName"];
textView.text = savedValue;
```

Hope it helps.. :)

Comment: Where is the textViewDidEndEditing?

Comment: Refer the apple docs - https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textViewDidEndEditing:

Answer (score 1):

There are several mechanisms available from iOS for storing data. Which one makes sense for you depends on the size and type of data you want to store and how you need to be able to use it.

A simple place to start might be `NSString`'s [`writeToFile:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:) (and also [Where You Should Put Your App’s Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW28)).